# CSV File showing random characteristics

Tags: csv

I copied a file from my ipad using iFunBox and I tried opened it with:

- Microsoft Excel
- FreeFileViewer
- Notepad
- Notepad++

All of them shown nothing File (.csv) Everytime open it using those 4 programmes this is what I get:

```
]   1   ˆ&ÓMF.¶•J¡ ñßR)åÙ¥e
ò¦Øœsl\V{`¸u°N±vI¦½™êk4“‡-m Ùò¾ˆÚär'²ø¢å:š nàÊ#‹8yH@uä³éc‹übuÙÀÙHIˆ[g¿^¶$9¹asï³`‰;*ý:Ôê]ÓlÆFJŠzÆy l[
 †nÒdzÙ› ™uê^ï:—ŽœÏ·`ð€‡°XR…Hù™6è³ß×+¥Û/‹ÐÉÞ‡çååw¿öùr~uóçˆKÝcýœó©û$R0áÓ)`´Á°ŠOŸ¸hÉw”ÕÌ$¾S|åÚ†G¾Ùú¿@/¯J(ÁÇ†‡Úøoä‡™ñyŠÃ©A°6ÀÊ¿©þFDBº·SáóDEa±€o¹Nê¦ä~iÿñÍQ‹òÊun¢ç,Æâðe IéŒ
```

Comment: That looks like what you get when you try to open a binary file. Are you sure it's a csv file and not a proprietary spreadsheet format?

Comment: Could also be a compressed format. Whatever it is, it is not a csv format and thus not a problem with that file format, but instead a problem of the application that created this file.

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to be binary and not CSV. CSV is a plain text file which depending on the text encoding may show some strange characters, but mainly plainly readable. The file above is a kind of OMF file, whatever that is.